# Qtcreator freeze with 100% CPU usage

Tags: c++, qt-creator, ubuntu-16.04, freeze

When I'm using Qtcreator3.5.1(based on Qt 5.5.1) on Ubuntu 16.04, i experience freeze, they often appears when I'm trying to do an auto completion ,right-click or just scrolling.
During theses freeze my CPU usage goes to 100%(for one core).
My project is not that big about 20 .h and .cpp files, with some files reaching 800 lines.
Does anybody have any idea of the cause of this ?

It seems that they had the same problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1577213
but the solution they proposed didnt't change anything for me.

Comment: You do realize that is a version from 2015, right?

Comment: Biggest trouble with such old versions is that if we now track down and fix that defect and put up pull request with fix then there is still very low likelihood that they will update it and release 3.5.2. Better install 4.5.2 and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

After a long and unsuccessful research, i just decided to switch to the newest version of Qtcreator. 
Now everything is fine, most of my settings was imported automatically.